# How can I force Spartacus to load a template

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

how can I get Spartacus to load a specific template from the backend when the main module don't get bootstraped (web-component)?

My use case is as follows:

I have a site which is build with accelerator. I would like to migrate it to Spartacus step by step. First the header, then the footer and then the rest (move from accelerator to SPA only).
My custom footer and header works in the Spartacus SPA. To integrate them into accelerator, I build web-components for the header and footer with [ngx-build-plus](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus). They work, but render only the static part of the component and not the slots of Spartacus. I also don't see the request to the backend.

AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    B2cStorefrontModule.withConfig({
      backend: {
        occ: {
          baseUrl: environment.occBaseUrl,
          prefix: environment.occPrefix,
        },
      },
      context: {
        baseSite: ['de'],
        language: ['en'],
        currency: ['EUR'],
        urlParameters: ['baseSite', 'language'],
      },
      i18n: {
        resources: translations,
        chunks: translationChunksConfig,
        fallbackLang: 'en',
      },
      features: {
        level: '2.1',
      },
      breakpoints: {
        xs: 576,
        sm: 768,
        md: 992,
        lg: 1920,
      },
      layoutSlots: {
        WebxHomepageTemplate: {
          slots: [],
        },
      },
    }),
    BrowserTransferStateModule,
    UiHeaderModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}
  ngDoBootstrap(): void {
    const elm = createCustomElement(AppComponent, { injector: this.injector });
    customElements.define('wc-header', elm);
  }
}
```

AppComponent template:

```
<cx-storefront>
  <ng-template cxOutletRef="header">
    <ui-header></ui-header>
  </ng-template>
</cx-storefront>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the logic related to layout loading is tied to the routing, inside `CmsPageGuard`, and in your case navigation is not happening.

So, you can either try faking it (do the navigation in your component) or try to do all the steps manually. I think, what's needed, is to set proper page context (`RoutingService.getPageContext()`) and call `CmsService.getPage` (or `hasPage`) to trigger the load. Not sure if this is all, but I think it's a good start (and you should have layout and slots data loaded).

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.

Comment: I configured the slots to be empty, because I want to have just the header. When I bootstrap the main module instead of using entryComponents it works as expected, the only one problem with that is that it changes the URL in the browser and I don't want that, because later I have two web-components which should only show the header/footer without touching the URL (on initial load).